# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated siempre es false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de recuperar el usuario logeado actualmente en mi sistema pero, por alguna razón la propiedad ***IsAuthenticated siempre me retorna un false***:

Estoy usando esta clase para fijar el usuario al contexto y para recuperar el usuario logeado, la cual esta en un proyecto del tipo Biblioteca de clases:

```
namespace Helper
{
public static class SessionHelper
{
    public static bool ExistUserInSession()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public static void DestroyUserSession()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
    public static int GetUser()
    {
        int user_id = 0;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket;
            if (ticket != null)
            {
                user_id = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.UserData);
            }
        }
        return user_id;
    }
    public static void AddUserToSession(string id)
    {
        bool persist = true;
        var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("usuario", persist);

        cookie.Name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);

        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, id);

        cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
}
```

Después de una validación de usuario y contraseña vs mi base de datos utilizo el método **AddUserToSession** para fijar el usuario a la sesión, si depuro esas lineas puedo ver como se genera la cookie y el ticket correctamente.

Esta es la parte del Action donde mando a llamar al método mencionado:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _usuarioViewModel.Email = model.Email;
        _usuarioViewModel.Password = model.Password;

        var usuarioDomain = Mapper.Map<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>(_usuarioViewModel);
        UsuarioDto usuarioDtoDomain = _userRepository.Login(usuarioDomain);

    //Si la autenticacion no fue exitosa la capa correspondiente regresa un CustomException
        if (usuarioDtoDomain != null)
        {
            SessionHelper.AddUserToSession(usuarioDtoDomain.UsuarioId.ToString());

            return View("~/views/home/index.cshtml");
        }
```

Bien, hasta aquí todo va bien se logea y aparentemente fija el usuarioId al contexto, el tema ocurre cuando pregunto por el usuario autenticado, desde la vista para mostrar el nombre de usuario:

```
 @if (SessionHelper.ExistUserInSession())
 {
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 text-center well">
         Bienvenido, <b>@FrontUser.Get().Email</b> [<a href="~/home/salir">Finalizar sesión</a>]
     </div>
 </div>
  }
```

Como ven SessionHelper es una clase estática pero por alguna razón al llamar a la función:

```
public static bool ExistUserInSession()
{
   return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Este siempre me regresa false.

Esta es la sección correspondiente del web.config.

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="prueba" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" />

</authentication> 
</system.web>
```

Si alguien con mas experiencia puede ver algo incorrecto mucho le agradeceré si me informa u ofrece algún tip para dar con el origen de mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

para solucionar el problema deberías crear la cookie de autenticación para el usuario proporcionado. Para ello antes de recuperar la cookie en el método AddUserToSession debes hacer FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(id, persist);

```
public static void AddUserToSession(string id)
{
    bool persist = true;
    // generar cookie de autenticación
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(id, persist);
    var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(id, persist);

    cookie.Name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);

    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, id);

    cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Lo siento @Mariano, edito mi respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

He tenido tu mismo problema y lo he solucionado editando Web.config añadiendo las siguientes líneas:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="prueba" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Por lo que leo ya lo has hecho pero quizás sirva para otras personas.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Define [loginUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl(v=vs.110).aspx) en el `web.config` :

suponiendo que tu página es `login.aspx`:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="prueba" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" />
  <forms loginUrl="~/home/login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/home/index.cshtml" />
</authentication> 
</system.web>
```

Comment: Hola: al agregar la linea que recomiendas no soluciono el problema. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si validamos el articulo

[Forms Authentication Configuration and Advanced Topics (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs)

Podras observar que usa

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
```

o sea no define un texto "usuario" fijo sino que usa el nombre del usuario que se ingresa en el login

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini, el seteo de la palabra usuario es solo para probar,  ya que para el resultado es independiente si envio el nombre de usuario como tal o si seteo algún valor, el resultado es el mimo, isAuthenticated siempre es false.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema y se debe a una configuración en el web.config que se agrega automáticamente al ocupar la clase "FormsAuthentication". Simplemente comenta la linea o elimina esta.

[image: Remove FormsAuthentication]

El código que describiste mas arriba, sumado a los comentarios y ajustes de los demás, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Evita poner imagenes. Escribe el código a mano para facilitar el trabajo al resto. Echale un vistazo a [answer]